# Setting onMenuItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, menuitem

I've tried to set a custom listener for my menu items, however wherever I try to do this I get a null from searching any menu item by id. It works fine with method `onOptionItemSelected()` in main activity, but that's ugly. I have tried to set up listeners in  `onCreateOptionsMenu()`,  `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and even in `onCreate()` but they all failed me - which method is the correct one to set listeners for menuItems?

Comment: What kind of code? It was just adding `MenuItem option = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.option1);` and then `option.set ....` at the end of all of the listed methods, and set always triggered NPE that said I can't use set on null.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take a reference to you menu when you inflate it, they menu items aren't part of the normal view hierarchy.

You can then easily get the menu item IDs from the saved menu reference, I've used this method before and it works, but it's not as clean as using the standard menu listeners.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if ( id == R.id.xxx ) {

       // logic
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, I want to set up an outside onMenuItemClickListener and put logic there.

Comment: To use a custom listener, Make custom layout .

Comment: Why? What for? I want custom listener to be a java class that handles the logic, I don't want to have any UI associated with it.

Comment: how to make interface and callback to logic ?
using android.view.menuitem.class

Comment: I don't think you know what I am asking for. I have a created a class X that implements OnMenuItemClicklistener and I want to bind X to menuItems in activity.

Comment: ((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar)).setOnMenuItemClickListener( your listener);